# how to convert radian to degree on Simulink scope axes

Tags: matlab, scope, matlab-figure, simulink

I want to change the scope axes from radian to degree
MATLAB Simulink shows radian (the axes by default).
I want to change this from rad to degree. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `R2D` block for converting from Radians to Degrees after you calculate `alpha_m`. If you want to do the conversion by yourself, then just add a `Gain` block with gain equal to `180/pi` instead.

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had done this method, but it causes the output of the scope to fluctuate and error
I am looking for a way to do this change without needing these blocks

Comment: The gain block has nothing to do with fluctuations, that must be because of some other block/setting, please add more details for other blocks to help us troubleshoot this.